# Table counts values double

Tags: r

I have a set of data called `viewed_at` (in `as.POSIXct` format), which looks like this:

> `[1] "2018-02-28 00:13:00 CET" "2018-02-28 01:52:00 CET"    [3]
>   "2018-02-28 01:52:00 CET" "2018-02-28 03:38:00 CET"    [5] "2018-02-28
>   04:53:00 CET" "2018-02-28 04:45:00 CET"    [7] "2018-02-28 04:41:00
>   CET" "2018-02-28 04:12:00 CET"    [9] "2018-02-28 05:53:00 CET"
>   "2018-02-28 05:32:00 CET"   [11] "2018-02-28 05:33:00 CET" "2018-02-28
>   05:31:00 CET"`

(The dataset is about 100.000 lines)

I want to match the dates and times that are equal and add the frequency next to it.

To do that I used:    `ts <- table(viewed_at)`

The output looks like this:

`2018-02-28 00:13:00 2018-02-28 01:52:00 2018-02-28 03:38:00 
                  2                   4                   2 
2018-02-28 04:53:00 2018-02-28 04:41:00 2018-02-28 04:45:00 
                  2                   2                   2`

It seems that everything is in order, but one thing is not: the frequency is doubled everywhere.

Of course, the solution is to divide every frequency by 2, but I really want to know why this happens.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

RC

Comment: See `?table()`...